# Server Monitoring iOS App

Tags: ios, background, ping

I'm fairly new to iOS Programming and I'm developing an App which will ping a specified server every 5 minutes and let the user know whether the server is up. So far I have been able to get everything working properly as long as the App is in the foreground and as soon as it's moved to the Background State it will not work. The problem is, I really have no idea which Background Mode I should select as none of those modes describe what App's function. I'm aware that I can accomplish this by creating a simple PHP script (Executed by CRON every 5 mins) which will ping the server and will send a APNS, But is there anyway I can accomplish what I'm trying to do without using APNS ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. In your case the only solution is to use `Push Notifications`.

`Local notifications` is not an option for you, since you need to call a method to ping the server, but iOS won't let your app to perform any code in `Background` mode. You may use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` method, but it's execution is [limited by 10 minutes](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios)

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrey for the quick reply. That's really sad though because then I have to make sure the server which I'm running the PHP script is 100% reliable :( Thanks again.